# Select last row by group for all columns data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I was surprised doing the following:

```
R) system.time(lastOrder <- order[,lapply(.SD,tail,1),by="TRADER_ID,EXEC_IDATE"]);
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       1.45        0.00        1.53 
R) nrow(order)
[1] 75301
R) ncol(order)
[1] 23
```

Thought it was very long, then I did

```
R) system.time(lastOrder <- order[,list(test=tail(EXEC_IDATE,1)),by="TRADER_ID,EXEC_IDATE"]);
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
       0.14        0.00        0.14
```

as far as I understand, if you know all the rows to select and work on most of the work is done, then I don't see why apply this to all columns should be 10x longer. Am I doing something wrong on the first bit of code, this is the only way I know to select last rows by group

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Last row by group :

```
DT[, .SD[.N], by="TRADER_ID,EXEC_IDATE"]            # (1)
```

or, faster (avoid use of `.SD` where possible, for speed) :

```
w = DT[, .I[.N], by="TRADER_ID,EXEC_IDATE"][[3]]    # (2)
DT[w]
```

Note that the following feature request will make approach (1) as fast as approach (2) :

[FR#2330  Optimize .SD[i] query to keep the elegance but make it faster unchanged.](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2330&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: May be like this it is even better `w = DT[, list(IDX=.I[.N]), by="TRADER_ID,EXEC_IDATE"]$IDX` and `DT[w]`

Comment: Looks like the feature request is now [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/613) and slated for data.table v. 2.0

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this? (Synthetic data meant to mimic what I can infer about yours from the question)

```
tmp <- data.table(id = sample(1:20, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
                  date = as.Date(as.integer(runif(n=1e6, min = 1e4, max = 1.1e4)),
                                 origin = as.Date("1970-01-01")),
                  data1 = rnorm(1e6),
                  data2 = rnorm(1e6),
                  data3 = rnorm(1e6))

> system.time(X <- tmp[, lapply(.SD, tail, 1), by = list(id, date)])
  user  system elapsed 
  1.95    0.00    1.95

> system.time(Y <- tmp[, list(tail(data1, 1)), by = list(id, date)])
  user  system elapsed 
  1.24    0.01    1.26 

> system.time({
    setkey(tmp, id, date)
    Z <- tmp[unique(tmp)[, key(tmp), with=FALSE], mult="last"]
})
  user  system elapsed 
  0.90    0.02    0.92
```

X and Z are the same after same order is ensured:

```
> identical(setkey(X, id, date), setkey(Z, id, date))
[1] TRUE
```

The difference between my `lapply` `tail` and 1-column `tail` isn't as drastic as yours, but without the structure of your data, it's hard to say more.

Also, note that most of the time in this method is setting the key.  If the table is already sorted by the grouping columns, it goes really fast:

```
> system.time(Z <- tmp[unique(tmp)[, key(tmp), with=FALSE], mult="last"])
  user  system elapsed 
  0.03    0.00    0.03
```

Alternatively, you could translate the many column problem to the 1-column problem with a temporary column:

```
> system.time({
  tmp[, row.num := seq_len(nrow(tmp))]
  W <- tmp[tmp[, max(row.num), by = list(id, date)]$V1][, row.num := NULL]
  tmp[, row.num := NULL]
})
user  system elapsed 
0.92    0.00    1.09 

> identical(setkey(X, id, date), setkey(W, id, date))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: addition to [@user1935457](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935457/user1935457): `Z1 <- tmp[, lapply(.SD, last), by = .(id, date)])` does the same job and is as fast as `X <- tmp[, lapply(.SD, tail, 1), by = list(id, date)]`