# Select first and last row from grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

**Question**

Using `dplyr`, how do I select the top and bottom observations/rows of grouped data in one statement?

**Data & Example**

Given a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 stopId=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                 stopSequence=c(1,2,3,3,1,4,3,1,2))
```

I can get the top and bottom observations from each group using `slice`, but using two separate statements:

```
firstStop <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(stopSequence) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup

lastStop <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(stopSequence) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup
```

Can I combine these two statements into one that selects *both* top and bottom observations?

Comment: See also [How to select the first and last row within a grouping variable in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/how-to-select-the-first-and-last-row-within-a-grouping-variable-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 327, accepted):

There is probably a faster way:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(stopSequence) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n())
```

Comment: `rownumber() %in% c(1, n())` would obviate the need to run vector scan twice

Comment: @MichaelChirico I suspect you omitted an `_`? i.e. `filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n()))`

Answer (score 141):

Just for completeness: You can pass `slice` a vector of indices:

```
df %>% arrange(stopSequence) %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(c(1,n()))
```

which gives

```
  id stopId stopSequence
1  1      a            1
2  1      c            3
3  2      b            1
4  2      c            4
5  3      b            1
6  3      a            3
```

Comment: might even be faster than `filter` - have not tested this, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27766197/7941188)

Comment: @Tjebo Unlike filter, slice can return the same row multiple times, eg `mtcars[1, ] %>% slice(c(1, n()))` so in that sense the choice between them depends on what you want returned. I'd expect the timings to be close unless `n` is very large (where slice might be favored), but haven't tested either.

Answer (score 19):

Not `dplyr`, but it's much more direct using `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[
  df[order(id, stopSequence), .(rows = .I[c(1L,.N)]), by=id]$rows
]
    #  rows stopId stopSequence
    # 1:  1      a            1
    # 2:  1      c            3
    # 3:  2      b            1
    # 4:  2      c            4
    # 5:  3      b            1
    # 6:  3      a            3
```

More detailed explanation:

```
# 1) get row numbers of first/last observations from each group
#    * basically, we sort the table by id/stopSequence, then,
#      grouping by id, name the row numbers of the first/last
#      observations for each id; since this operation produces
#      a data.table
#    * .I is data.table shorthand for the row number
#    * here, to be maximally explicit, I've named the variable rows
#      as row_num to give other readers of my code a clearer
#      understanding of what operation is producing what variable
first_last = df[order(id, stopSequence), .(rows = .I[c(1L,.N)]), by=id]
idx = first_last$rows

# 2) extract rows by number
df[idx]
```

Be sure to check out the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) wiki for getting the `data.table` basics covered

Comment: Or `df[ df[order(stopSequence), .I[c(1,.N)], keyby=id]$V1 ]`. Seeing `id` appear twice is weird to me.

Comment: You can set keys in the `setDT` call. So an `order` call no need here.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov - you may not always want to set the keys, though.

Comment: Or `df[order(stopSequence), .SD[c(1L,.N)], by = id]`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155807/4241780)

Comment: @JWilliman that won't necessarily be _exactly_ the same, since it won't reorder on `id`. I think `df[order(stopSequence), .SD[c(1L, .N)], keyby = id]` should do the trick (with the minor difference to the solution above that the result will be `key`ed

Comment: @MichaelChirico how would u do this if u want the last instead of first?

Comment: @Keweik I don't follow -- the question is about first _and_ last. My answer shows how to do both simultaneously. Just use `.N` alone for last only, or `1L` alone for first only.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, i see, sorry my bad.

Comment: @keweik don't sweat it :)

Answer (score 11):

using `which.min` and `which.max` :

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(c(which.min(stopSequence), which.max(stopSequence)))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id stopId stopSequence
#>   <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>
#> 1     1 a                 1
#> 2     1 c                 3
#> 3     2 b                 1
#> 4     2 c                 4
#> 5     3 b                 1
#> 6     3 a                 3
```

**benchmark**

It is also much faster than the current accepted answer because we find the min and max value by group, instead of sorting the whole stopSequence column.

```
# create a 100k times longer data frame
df2 <- bind_rows(replicate(1e5, df, F)) 
bench::mark(
  mm =df2 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice(c(which.min(stopSequence), which.max(stopSequence))),
  jeremy = df2 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(stopSequence) %>%
    filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n()))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 mm           22.6ms     27ms     34.9     14.2MB     21.3
#> 2 jeremy      254.3ms    273ms      3.66    58.4MB     11.0
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 stopId=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                 stopSequence=c(1,2,3,3,1,4,3,1,2))

first_last <- function(x) {
  bind_rows(slice(x, 1), slice(x, n()))
}

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(stopSequence) %>%
  do(first_last(.)) %>%
  ungroup

## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## 
##   id stopId stopSequence
## 1  1      a            1
## 2  1      c            3
## 3  2      b            1
## 4  2      c            4
## 5  3      b            1
## 6  3      a            3
```

With `do` you can pretty much perform any number of operations on the group but @jeremycg's answer is way more appropriate for just this task.

Comment: Hadn't considered writing a function - certainly a good way of doing something more complex.

Comment: This seems overcomplicated compared to just using `slice`, like `df %>% arrange(stopSequence) %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(c(1,n()))`

Comment: Not disagreeing (and I pointed to jeremycg's as a better answer _in_ the post) but having a `do` example here might help others when `slice` won't work (i.e. more complex operations on a group). And, you shld post your comment as an answer (it's the best one).

Answer (score 10):

I know the question specified `dplyr`. But, since others already posted solutions using other packages, I decided to have a go using other packages too:

Base package:

```
df <- df[with(df, order(id, stopSequence, stopId)), ]
merge(df[!duplicated(df$id), ], 
      df[!duplicated(df$id, fromLast = TRUE), ], 
      all = TRUE)
```

data.table:

```
df <-  setDT(df)
df[order(id, stopSequence)][, .SD[c(1,.N)], by=id]
```

sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
min <- sqldf("SELECT id, stopId, min(stopSequence) AS StopSequence
      FROM df GROUP BY id 
      ORDER BY id, StopSequence, stopId")
max <- sqldf("SELECT id, stopId, max(stopSequence) AS StopSequence
      FROM df GROUP BY id 
      ORDER BY id, StopSequence, stopId")
sqldf("SELECT * FROM min
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM max")
```

In one query:

```
sqldf("SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT id, stopId, min(stopSequence) AS StopSequence
              FROM df GROUP BY id 
              ORDER BY id, StopSequence, stopId)
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT id, stopId, max(stopSequence) AS StopSequence
              FROM df GROUP BY id 
              ORDER BY id, StopSequence, stopId)")
```

Output:

```
  id stopId StopSequence
1  1      a            1
2  1      c            3
3  2      b            1
4  2      c            4
5  3      a            3
6  3      b            1
```

Answer (score 6):

This works fine:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(stopSequence) %>%
  slice(1,n())

# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id stopId stopSequence
#  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
#1     1 a                 1
#2     1 c                 3
#3     2 b                 1
#4     2 c                 4
#5     3 b                 1
#6     3 a                 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`:

```
# convert to data.table
setDT(df) 
# order, group, filter
df[order(stopSequence)][, .SD[c(1, .N)], by = id]

   id stopId stopSequence
1:  1      a            1
2:  1      c            3
3:  2      b            1
4:  2      c            4
5:  3      b            1
6:  3      a            3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with lapply and a dplyr statement. We can apply an arbitrary number of whatever summary functions to the same statement:

```
lapply(c(first, last), 
       function(x) df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(funs(x))) %>% 
bind_rows()
```

You could for example be interested in rows with the max stopSequence value as well and do:

```
lapply(c(first, last, max("stopSequence")), 
       function(x) df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(funs(x))) %>%
bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1):

A different base R alternative would be to first `order` by `id` and `stopSequence`, `split` them based on `id` and for every `id` we select only the first and last index and subset the dataframe using those indices.

```
df[sapply(with(df, split(order(id, stopSequence), id)), function(x) 
                   c(x[1], x[length(x)])), ]


#  id stopId stopSequence
#1  1      a            1
#3  1      c            3
#5  2      b            1
#6  2      c            4
#8  3      b            1
#7  3      a            3
```

---

Or similar using `by`

```
df[unlist(with(df, by(order(id, stopSequence), id, function(x) 
                   c(x[1], x[length(x)])))), ]
```