# Use dplyr to take first and last row in a sequence by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to take the first and last rows of repeated values by group. I'm doing this for efficiency reasons, particularly so that graphing is faster.

This is not a duplicate of [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data) because I'm not asking for the strict first and last row in a group; I'm asking for the first and last row in a group *by level* (in my case 1's and 0's) that may appear in multiple chunks.

Here's an example. Say I want to remove all the redundant 1's and 0's from column C while keeping A and B intact.

```
df = data.frame(
    A = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 10),
    B = rep(c(1:10), 2),
    C = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1))

A  B C
a  1 1
a  2 0
a  3 0
a  4 0
a  5 0
a  6 0
a  7 1
a  8 1
a  9 1
a 10 1
b  1 0
b  2 0
b  3 0
b  4 1
b  5 0
b  6 0
b  7 0
b  8 0
b  9 0
b 10 1
```

The end result should look like this:

```
A  B C
a  1 1
a  2 0
a  6 0
a  7 1
a 10 1
b  1 0
b  3 0
b  4 1
b  5 0
b  9 0
b 10 1
```

Using `unique` will either not remove anything or just take one of the 1's or 0's without retaining the start-and-end quality that I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way to do this without a loop, perhaps using `dplyr` or `forcats`?

Comment: @zx8754 I edited my question to detail what I see as differences between what I'm asking and the question you linked to. They get at different outcomes that, for example, have useful ramifications for longitudinal cohort data.

Comment: In base R the unwieldy `df[unique(unlist(tapply(seq_along(df$C), list(df$A, cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(df$C))))), FUN=function(i) c(head(i,1), tail(i, 1))))),]` works for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `slice` should get you close:

```
df %>%
  group_by(A,C) %>%
  slice(c(1, n()))
```

gives

```
      A     B     C
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1     a     2     0
2     a     6     0
3     a     1     1
4     a    10     1
5     b     1     0
6     b     9     0
7     b     4     1
8     b    10     1
```

though this doesn't quite match your expected outcome. n() gives the last row in the group.

After your edit it is clear that you are not looking for the values within any group that is established (which is what my previous version did). You want to group by those runs of 1's or 0's. For that, you will need to create a column that checks whether or not the run of 1's/0's has changed and then one to identify the groups. Then, `slice` will work as described before. However, because some of your runs are only 1 row long, we need to only include `n()` if it is more than 1 (otherwise the 1 row shows up twice).

```
df %>%
  mutate(groupChanged = (C != lag(C, default = C[1]))
         , toCutBy = cumsum(groupChanged)
         ) %>%
  group_by(toCutBy) %>%
  slice(c(1, ifelse(n() == 1, NA, n())))
```

Gives

```
       A     B     C groupChanged toCutBy
   <chr> <int> <dbl>        <lgl>   <int>
1      a     1     1        FALSE       0
2      a     2     0         TRUE       1
3      a     6     0        FALSE       1
4      a     7     1         TRUE       2
5      a    10     1        FALSE       2
6      b     1     0         TRUE       3
7      b     3     0        FALSE       3
8      b     4     1         TRUE       4
9      b     5     0         TRUE       5
10     b     9     0        FALSE       5
11     b    10     1         TRUE       6
```

If the runs of 1 or 0 must stay within the level in column `A`, you also need to add a check for a change in column `A` to the call. In this example, it does not have an effect (so returns exactly the same values), but it may be desirable in other instances.

```
df %>%
  mutate(groupChanged = (C != lag(C, default = C[1]) |
                           A != lag(A, default = A[1]))
         , toCutBy = cumsum(groupChanged)
  ) %>%
  group_by(toCutBy) %>%
  slice(c(1, ifelse(n() == 1, NA, n())))
```

Comment: Interesting, that's better than what I've been doing. It's still missing a few rows... like a-7, b-3, and b-5. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question/answer attracted such a downvote brigade. Upvoted for useful contribution.

Comment: I noticed that you didn't do group_by(A); did intend to leave it out or is it superfluous?

Comment: Your question only specified that column `C` controlled the groups -- I've added an approach that also checks if `A` changed (gives the same output in this example)

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I tried to provide an illustrative example but it was difficult to make a minimal/reproducible example that was also generalizable to future users.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
C_filter <- function(x) {
    !sapply(1:length(x), function(i) {
        identical(x[i], x[i-1])
    }) | !sapply(1:length(x), function(i) {
        identical(x[i], x[i+1])
    }) 
}
df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(C_filter(C))

   A  B C
1  a  1 1
2  a  2 0
3  a  6 0
4  a  7 1
5  a 10 1
6  b  1 0
7  b  3 0
8  b  4 1
9  b  5 0
10 b  9 0
11 b 10 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question/answer attracted such a downvote brigade. Upvoted for useful contribution.