# Creating new column based on repeated consecutive row entries

Tags: r, pivot, tidy, dtplyr

Imagine a snippet of the follow data frame:

```
       ID        ActivityName     Time         Type    Shape 
1       1             Request    0.000       Type_1      767           
2       1             Request  600.000       Type_1      767           
3       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376           
4       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376  
5       1               Delay 2962.295       Type_1     1022         
6       1 Schedule Activities  600.000       Type_1       15           
7       1 Schedule Activities 2062.295       Type_1       15
```

What I'm trying to do is to create two new columns based on the repeating entries in *ActivityName*.

Specifically, I want to combine two subsequent rows for the same activity into one row with a start and complete timestamp (from Time, in seconds).

Given that not all entries in *ActivityName* have a matching second entry (however, max two consecutive entries are identical), I would also like to delete such rows, as *Delay* in this case.

It should then look something like:

```
       ID        ActivityName  StartTime   EndTime      Type    Shape 
1       1             Request  0.000       600.000      Type_1  767           
2       1               Start  600.000     600.000      Type_1  1375
3       1 Schedule Activities  600.000     2062.295     Type_1  15
```

All categories in *ActivityName* occur many times in that column. I hope not to compare their associated *Time* not across the whole column, only those who have two consecutive identical occurrence.

Any ideas for how to go about this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Having reproducible data will help you get answers. You can use the dput function to help.

Comment: @Alex - I just saw your previous question which looked identical to this one. It might help to revise your question with a more complete example, where the other solution failed, and provide the desired result. For instance, can you add examples of the *single standing* rows? And other situations where the previous solution doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df<-data.frame(activity_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
               time = c(0,2,2,4,4,6))
df
```

> ```
>   activity_name time
> 1             A    0
> 2             A    2
> 3             B    2
> 4             B    4
> 5             C    4
> 6             C    6
> ```

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(activity_name) %>% 
  summarise(StartTime = first(time),
            EndTime = last(time))
```

> ```
>   activity_name StartTime EndTime
>   <fct>             <dbl>   <dbl>
> 1 A                     0       2
> 2 B                     2       4
> 3 C                     4       6
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks! This is almost it - the problem is that when having more instances of "A"s, "B"s, "C"s etc in activity_name., this always checks the whole column to obtain their minimum and maximum associated time values. Instead, I'm trying to compare them locally, i.e. two consecutively occurring A's have a StartTime and EndTime independent of another pair of consecutive A's.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing activity_name groups locally. Making a new field to group by, that identifies when the local group changes.

```
df<-data.frame(activity_name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A"),
               time = c(0,2,2,4,4,6,99))
```

> ```
>   activity_name time
> 1             A    0
> 2             A    2
> 3             B    2
> 4             B    4
> 5             C    4
> 6             C    6
> 7             A   99
> ```

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(groupChanged = (activity_name != lag(activity_name, default = activity_name[1])),
         toCutBy = cumsum(groupChanged)) %>% 
  group_by(toCutBy) %>%
  summarise(activity_name = first(activity_name),
            StartTime = first(time),
            EndTime = last(time))
```

> ```
>   toCutBy activity_name StartTime EndTime
> 1       0 A                     0       2
> 2       1 B                     2       4
> 3       2 C                     4       6
> 4       3 A                    99      99
> ```

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127176/10276092