# Get last row of each group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have some data similar in structure to:

```
a <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
                "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
```

And I am trying to sort it by `ID` and `NUM` then get the last row.
This code works to get the last row and summarize down to a unique ID, however, it doesn't actually get the full last row like I want.

```
a <- a %>% arrange(ID, NUM) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(max(NUM))
```

I understand why this code doesn't work but am looking for the `dplyr` way of getting the last row for each unique `ID`

Expected Results:

```
  ID        NUM     VAL
  <fct    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A           2       0
2 B           4       1
3 C           9       0
```

Note: I will admit that though it is nearly a duplicate of [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data), the answers on that thread were not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might try:

```
a %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(NUM) %>%  
  slice(n())
```

Answer (score 17):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
a %>%
 arrange(ID, NUM) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise_all(last)

  ID      NUM   VAL
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        2.    0.
2 B        4.    1.
3 C        9.    0.
```

Or since `dplyr 1.0.0`:

```
a %>%
 arrange(ID, NUM) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(across(everything(), last))
```

Or using `slice_max()`:

```
a %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice_max(order_by = NUM, n = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

`tail()` returns the last 6 items of a subsettable object. When using `aggregate()`, the parameters to the `FUN` argument are passed immediately after the function using a comma; here `1` refers to `n = 1`, which tells `tail()` to only return the last item.

```
aggregate(a[, c('NUM', 'VAL')], list(a$ID), tail, 1)

# Group.1 NUM VAL
# 1       A   2   0
# 2       B   3   0
# 3       C   9   0
```

Comment: Would be helpful to wrap this in some explanation of what this does, and why it solves the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top_n`. (grouping already sorts by `ID`, and sorting by `NUM` isn't necessary since there's only 1 value)

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  top_n(1, NUM)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [3]
#   ID      NUM   VAL
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         2     0
# 2 B         4     1
# 3 C         9     0
```