# How to assign value to last row of group in R?

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620750/get-last-row-of-each-group-in-r), I want to select the last row of each group and assign a value to it.

```
 a <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
                 "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
 
 ID NUM VAL
  A   1   1
  A   2   0
  B   4   1
  B   3   0
  C   6   1
  C   9   0
```

My desired output:

```
 ID NUM VAL end.spell
  A   1   1         0
  A   2   0         1
  B   4   1         0
  B   3   0         1
  C   6   1         0
  C   9   0         1
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `group_by()` from `dplyr`, you could identify cases where the row number is the same as the number of rows for that group and give a 1 for that observation and zero otherwise.

```r
library(dplyr)
a <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
                "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))


a %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(end.spell = ifelse(row_number() == n(), 1,0))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>   ID      NUM   VAL end.spell
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 A         1     1         0
#> 2 A         2     0         1
#> 3 B         4     1         0
#> 4 B         3     0         1
#> 5 C         6     1         0
#> 6 C         9     0         1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Determine group `length` and store in `len`, create `integer` vector of nulls of length `len` and `replace` element number corresponding to `len` with `1L`. Done in `ave` on *ID*s by *ID*s*.

```
> transform(a, end=ave(ID, ID, FUN=\(x) {
+   len <- length(x)
+   replace(integer(len), len, 1L)
+ }))
  ID NUM VAL end
1  A   1   1   0
2  A   2   0   1
3  B   4   1   0
4  B   3   0   1
5  C   6   1   0
6  C   9   0   1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(a)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), NUM = c(1, 
2, 4, 3, 6, 9), VAL = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `last()`:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% 
  mutate(end.spell = ifelse(VAL == last(VAL), 1, 0))
```

```
  ID NUM VAL end.spell
1  A   1   1         0
2  A   2   0         1
3  B   4   1         0
4  B   3   0         1
5  C   6   1         0
6  C   9   0         1
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R implementation:

```
a <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
            "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
            "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))

max_idxs <- sapply(unique(a$ID), \(x) tail(which(a$ID == x), 1))
a$end.spell <- ifelse(1:nrow(a) %in% max_idxs, 1, 0)
```

And a data.table implementation:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
                "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))
a[, end.spell := ifelse(1:.N == .N, 1, 0), by = ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

**data.table**

```r
df <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                "NUM" = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
                "VAL" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0))

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df) %>%
  .[, end.spell := 0] %>%
  .[df[, .I[.N], by = ID]$V1, end.spell := 1] %>%
  .[]
#>    ID NUM VAL end.spell
#> 1:  A   1   1         0
#> 2:  A   2   0         1
#> 3:  B   4   1         0
#> 4:  B   3   0         1
#> 5:  C   6   1         0
#> 6:  C   9   0         1
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>