# How to select last N observation from each group in dplyr dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), b = c(34, 
343, 54, 11, 55, 62, 59, -9, 0, -0.5)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to take last N observations / rows from each group:

```
df %>% 
dplyr::group_by(a) %>% 
dplyr::last(2)
```

Gives me wrong results.

I want it to be:

```
a   b
1 343
1  54
2  55
2  62
3  59
3  -9
4   0
4  -0.5
```

Please advise what is wrong here?

The error I get is:

> Error in order(order_by)[[n]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As it is a specific question based on `dplyr`

**1**)  after the `group_by`, use `slice` on the `row_number()`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   slice(tail(row_number(), 2))
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   a [4]
#      a      b
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1  343  
#2     1   54  
#3     2   55  
#4     2   62  
#5     3   59  
#6     3   -9  
#7     4    0  
#8     4   -0.5
```

---

**2**) Or use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   filter(row_number() >= (n() - 1))
```

---

**3**) or with `do` and `tail`

```
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>% 
    do(tail(., 2))
```

---

**4**) In addition to the `tidyverse`, methods, we can also use compact `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[tail(seq_len(.N), 2)], a]$V1]
```

---

**5**) Or `by` from `base R`

```
by(df, df$a, FUN = tail, 2)
```

**6**) or with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
df[aggregate(c ~ a, transform(df, c = seq_len(nrow(df))), FUN = tail, 2)$c,]
```

**7**) or with `split` from `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$a), tail, 2))
```

Comment: Why not with the tail function?

Comment: @steves  If you do `df %>% group_by(a) %>% tail(2)`, it will get you the last 2 rows of the whole dataset and not within the group

Comment: and last() function?

Comment: @steves `last` is used in a different context within `sumarise/mutate` to get the `last` element of a particular column.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

[dplyr 1.1.0](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#dplyr-110) introduced the `.by`/`by` argument to `slice()` family of verbs to allow for one-time grouping operations:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 2, by = a)
```

Note: at this time `by` is experimental.

---

[dplyr 1.0.0](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#dplyr-100) introduced [`slice_tail`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) that makes this simple:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  slice_tail(n = 2)
```

Similarly, there is `slice_head` to get the *first* `n` rows.

Comment: Do not forget to pipe to `ungroup`, if that is necessary for your pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `tapply` is to subset the last two rows for every group.

```
df[unlist(tapply(1:nrow(df), df$a, tail, 2)), ]

#     a      b
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1  343  
#2     1   54  
#3     2   55  
#4     2   62  
#5     3   59  
#6     3   -9  
#7     4    0  
#8     4   -0.5
```

---

Or another option using `ave`

```
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(1:nrow(df), a, FUN = function(x) x %in% tail(x, 2)))), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a `tidyverse` possibility:

```
df %>%
 group_by(a) %>%
 top_n(2, row_number())

      a        b
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1    1.  343.   
2    1.   54.0  
3    2.   55.0  
4    2.   62.0  
5    3.   59.0  
6    3.   -9.00 
7    4.    0.   
8    4.   -0.500
```

It is taking the top two rows given the row numbers per groups.

Comment: I need the last N rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tail()`.In R `head` function allows you to preview the first n rows, while `tail` allows you to preview last n rows.

Comment: Note for future readers. As stated by @akrun in his reply, `tail()` function works within the entire table, not working with `group_by()`. As @LMc says, use `slice_tail()` from `dplyr`