# How to have R create a data frame using the last two months

Tags: r, max, lubridate

Below is a sample data set

```
 area    periodyear    period  employment     date
 01         2020         08       100         2020-08-01
 01         2020         09       105         2020-09-01
 01         2020         10       110         2020-10-01
 02         2020         08       101         2020-08-01
 02         2020         09       102         2020-09-01
 02         2020         10       103         2020-10-01
```

The question is how I get R to return the last TWO rows. I created the date using the following code as a way of having a single value (instead of periodyear and period) that a max value can be found for.
substate$date<- ymd(paste(substate$PERIODYEAR,substate$PERIOD,"1",sep="-"))

I know how to have it find the max value of a column (date, in this instance) but unclear how to have it create a data frame that looks like below

```
 area    periodyear    period  employment     date
 01         2020         09       105         2020-09-01
 01         2020         10       110         2020-10-01
 02         2020         09       102         2020-09-01
 02         2020         10       103         2020-10-01
```

The reason for wanting the last TWO is that one month is brand new data and the one before is revised. From here, I update a SQL database.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994497/how-to-select-last-n-observation-from-each-group-in-dplyr-dataframe I think this answers what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `slice` after `arrange`ing the 'area', and the `Date` class converted 'date' (if they are not in the order)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(area, as.Date(date)) %>%
   group_by(area) %>%
   slice_tail(n = 2) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  area  periodyear period employment date      
#  <chr>      <int>  <int>      <int> <chr>     
#1 01          2020      9        105 2020-09-01
#2 01          2020     10        110 2020-10-01
#3 02          2020      9        102 2020-09-01
#4 02          2020     10        103 2020-10-01
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(area = c("01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02"), 
    periodyear = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), 
    period = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L), employment = c(100L, 
    105L, 110L, 101L, 102L, 103L), date = c("2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", 
    "2020-10-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01")), 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think it's not entirely clear from the TO's message, but I think they are rather looking for the two max dates per area.

Comment: @deschen thanks, i updated with `arrange`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% arrange(area,date) %>% group_by(area)  %>%filter(row_number() %in% 2:n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   area [2]
   area periodyear period employment date      
  <int>      <int>  <int>      <int> <date>    
1     1       2020      9        105 2020-09-01
2     1       2020     10        110 2020-10-01
3     2       2020      9        102 2020-09-01
4     2       2020     10        103 2020-10-01
```

Comment: @TimWilcox Fantastic, as you accepted one answer if you liked this you could upvote +1 :)