# Iterating across multiple data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have the following data frame:

Column 1 contains IDs with repeats, e.g. 001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002

Column 2 contains dates dates of service, e.g. 01-01-20, 01-02-20, 01-04-20, 01-05-20

Column 3 contains numerical data taken on those dates, e.g. 3, 4, 6, 3

For each client ID, I need to first find the earliest date that ID was serviced and determine what number was taken on that date (the First Number Taken for each client). Then, for each client, I need to compare their First Number Taken with all subsequent numbers taken for that client, and note the client ID if any subsequent number is higher than the First Number Taken.

Any help on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use `dput(your_data)` to show some data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select last N observation from each group in dplyr dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994497/how-to-select-last-n-observation-from-each-group-in-dplyr-dataframe)