# R - pick up a value from row after and add as new column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

```
> df <- data.frame('unique_ref' = c("a_2016","a_2017","a_2017","a_2016","a_2016"),
+                  'trans_type' = c('NB','NB','CANC','MTA','MTA'),
+                  'incept_dt' = c('01/01/2016','01/01/2017','01/01/2017','01/01/2016','01/01/2016'),
+                  'exp_dt' = c('31/12/2016','31/12/2017','31/12/2017','31/12/2016','31/12/2016'),
+                  'trans_dt' = c('01/01/2016','01/01/2017','01/03/2017','01/07/2016','01/09/2016'))
> df
  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt
1     a_2016         NB 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/01/2016
2     a_2017         NB 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/01/2017
3     a_2017       CANC 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/03/2017
4     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/07/2016
5     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/09/2016
```

I have the above dataset format which has a unique_ref and a few dates. I want to be able to sort this dataset by the unique ref and incept_dt and trans_dt:

```
> df %>% arrange(unique_ref,incept_dt,trans_dt)
  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt
1     a_2016         NB 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/01/2016
2     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/07/2016
3     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/09/2016
4     a_2017         NB 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/01/2017
5     a_2017       CANC 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/03/2017
```

Now with this sorted dataset I want to create a new column called trans_end_dt which looks at the row below and picks up that rows trans_dt less 1 day. It should do this for every unique_ref, but stop once it has reached the final unique_ref in that grouping and pick up the exp_dt. I.e. the result should be:

```
> df %>% arrange(unique_ref,incept_dt,trans_dt)
  unique_ref trans_type  incept_dt     exp_dt   trans_dt trans_end_dt
1     a_2016         NB 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/01/2016 30/06/2016 #this is 01/07/2016 minus one day
2     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/07/2016 31/08/2016 #same logic as above
3     a_2016        MTA 01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/09/2016 31/12/2016 #next row is a new unique_ref so the value should just be the exp_dt which is 31/12/2016
4     a_2017         NB 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/01/2017 28/02/2017
5     a_2017       CANC 01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/03/2017 31/12/2017
```

Does anyone know how I can do this? Preferably using dplyr but I am struggling to get this to work so any solution would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was to:

- Change columns ending in dt to `Date` format
- Sort as previously done by `unique_ref,incept_dt,trans_dt`
- For each unique_ref (using `group_by`) check if last row in group; if it is, use `exp_dt`, and if not, use `lead(trans_dt)` to get the following row data element and subtract 1

  ```
  library(dplyr)

  df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_dt")), as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y") %>%
    arrange(unique_ref,incept_dt,trans_dt) %>%
    group_by(unique_ref) %>%
    mutate(trans_end_dt = if_else(row_number() == n(), exp_dt,  lead(trans_dt) - 1))

    unique_ref trans_type incept_dt  exp_dt     trans_dt   trans_end_dt
    <fct>      <fct>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>      
  1 a_2016     NB         2016-01-01 2016-12-31 2016-01-01 2016-06-30  
  2 a_2016     MTA        2016-01-01 2016-12-31 2016-07-01 2016-08-31  
  3 a_2016     MTA        2016-01-01 2016-12-31 2016-09-01 2016-12-31  
  4 a_2017     NB         2017-01-01 2017-12-31 2017-01-01 2017-02-28  
  5 a_2017     CANC       2017-01-01 2017-12-31 2017-03-01 2017-12-31
  ```

**Edit**: As suggested by @Gregor, you can alternatively replace `if/else` with `coalesce` (which will fill in `NA` values):

```
mutate(trans_end_dt = coalesce(lead(trans_dt) - 1, exp_dt))
```

**Edit**: The `group_by` statement is needed so that the following operations after the `%>%` pipe are performed "by group." Even though the data has been sorted via `arrange`, the following mutate statement would consider *all* of the rows at one time, instead of subgroups a_2016, a_2017, etc. individually.

This is necessary for `row_number() == n()` where it compares the row number evaluated within the group to the total number of rows in the group (see [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data) regarding selecting last row of grouped data).

For example, when `unique_ref` is grouped, there are 3 rows (`n() = 3`) for `a_2016`, so if `row_number()` is 3, essentially the third line in the a_2016 group (or last in the group), then use `exp_dt`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain how row_number() == n() works? Why do we need to group_by here when it is already grouped?

Comment: Please see edited answer and let me know if helpful.

Comment: One suggestion, I think you could replace the `ifelse` with `trans_end_dt = coalesce(lead(train_dt) - 1, exp_dt)`. `lead` will give an `NA` if there is nothing in the next row, and `coalesce` is useful for filling in `NA`s, a little more cleanly than `ifelse`

Comment: Thank you - will edit and provide as alternative in answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` with the default being the last day of `exp_dt`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  arrange(unique_ref,incept_dt,trans_dt)%>%
  group_by(unique_ref)%>%
  mutate(trans_end_dt = strftime(lead(dmy(trans_dt)-1,1,dmy(exp_dt[n()])),"%d/%m/%Y"))#or format instead of strptime

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   unique_ref [2]
  unique_ref trans_type incept_dt  exp_dt     trans_dt   trans_end_dt
  <fct>      <fct>      <fct>      <fct>      <fct>      <chr>       
1 a_2016     NB         01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/01/2016 30/06/2016  
2 a_2016     MTA        01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/07/2016 31/08/2016  
3 a_2016     MTA        01/01/2016 31/12/2016 01/09/2016 31/12/2016  
4 a_2017     NB         01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/01/2017 28/02/2017  
5 a_2017     CANC       01/01/2017 31/12/2017 01/03/2017 31/12/2017
```