# Filter for first 5 observations per group in tidyverse

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

I have precipitation data of several different measurement locations and would like to filter for only the first n observations per location and per group of precipitation intensity using `tidyverse` functions.

So far, I've grouped the data by location and by precipitation intensity.

This is a minimal example (there are several observations of each rainfall intensity per location)

```
df <- data.frame(location = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 7)),
                 rain = c(1:7, 1:7))

   location rain
1         1    1
2         1    2
3         1    3
4         1    4
5         1    5
6         1    6
7         1    7
8         2    1
9         2    2
10        2    3
11        2    4
12        2    5
13        2    6
14        2    7
```

I thought that it should be quite easy using `group_by()` and `filter()`, but so far, I haven't found an expression that would return only the first n observations per rain group per location.

```
 df %>% group_by(rain, location) %>% filter(???)
```

Comment: data can't be reproduce (throws an error).

Comment: arguably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(location) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:5)
```

**Non-dplyr solutions** (that also rearrange the rows)

```
# Base R
df[unlist(lapply(split(row.names(df), df$location), "[", 1:5)), ]

# data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:5], by = location]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 slice(1:5)

   location  rain
      <dbl> <int>
 1        1     1
 2        1     2
 3        1     3
 4        1     4
 5        1     5
 6        2     1
 7        2     2
 8        2     3
 9        2     4
10        2     5
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[seq_len(.N) <=5], location]
```