# Filter grouped data in r

Tags: r, filter

I've a large grouped data I would like to filter. The sample data is shown below.

```
 Data <- data.frame (ID1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Score1 = c(360,360,360,250,250,250,195,195,195), ID2 = c(7,8,9,7,225,98,7,225,174), Score2 = c(330,150,100,330,275,180,330,275,210))
```

Edit: Pasting an alternate example that has an edge case not in the original:

```
Data <- data.frame (ID1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), Score1 = c(360,360,360,250,250,250,195,195,195), ID2 = c(7,8,9,7,8,98,7,225,174), Score2 = c(330,275,100,330,275,180,330,275,210))
```

The data is grouped by ID1 and I would like to filter the first row of each group but if ID2 is selected by the previous group, it'll no longer be a candidate for the next group.

The expected outcome for the alternate example is:

```
Data_Filtered <- data.frame (ID1 = c(1,2,3), Score1 = c(360,250,195), ID2 = c(7,8,225), Score2 = c(330,275,275))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'ID1' and `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%         
    distinct(ID2, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(ID1) %>% 
    slice(1)
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset, one option is

```
lst1 <- split(Data, Data$ID1)
out <- lst1[[1]][1,]
for(i in 2:length(lst1)) {
    out <- rbind(out, lst1[[i]][!lst1[[i]]$ID2 %in% out$ID2,][1,])
 }
out
#  ID1 Score1 ID2 Score2
#1   1    360   7    330
#5   2    250   8    275
#8   3    195 225    275
```

Comment: It works for the case offered but doesn't work if the next item was in any order within the previous group. So it doesn't actually keep track properly the previous selections.

Comment: @akrun Do you have a better idea to address the alternate example - 42 included in the question? Thank you.

Comment: @user9899857 Can you please update your question with the expected output for that as I find some inconsistencies in that example

Comment: @akrun I just updated the expected outcome. Thanks.

Comment: @BMM Updated the post.  Sorry, I forgot about this.