# Removing middle row using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, duplicates

There are 42 rows in my dataset(EP) and i want to remove the middle entries for participants. The follow code works but its giving an error:

> Error in if (EP$Name[row] == EP$Name[row + 1]) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
for (row in 2:length(EP$Name)){

    if(EP$Name[row] == EP$Name[row+1]) 
    {
        if(EP$Name[row]==EP$Name[row-1])
        {
         EP <- EP[-row,]
          print(row)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i <- c(1, with(rle(EP$Name), 1+cumsum(head(lengths, -1))));
EP[i, ]`

Comment: or `i <- c(TRUE, !(head(EP$Name, -1) == tail(EP$Name, -1))); EP[i, ]`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because of the last possible value of `row`
When `row=length(EP$Name)` , `EP$Name[row+1]` is not defined.

Your dataframe is small so it does not really matter here, but it's good to know that you should avoid loops on dataframes in R, you can have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data) to see how you could do without a loop here.

Answer (score 0):

In R, very rarely you'll need to use `for` loop explicitly.

Here, it seems you are trying to remove rows where `Name` is same as the previous row or the next row. You can use `lag` and `lead` in `dplyr` to get previous or next row respectively.

```
library(dplyr)
EP %>% filter(Name != lag(Name) & Name != lead(Name))
```

Or in `data.table` we can use `shift` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(EP)[Name != shift(Name) & Name != shift(Name, type = 'lead')]
```