# keep last non missing observation for all variables by group

Tags: r, data.table, coalesce

My data has multiple columns and some of those columns have missing values in different rows. I would like to group (collapse) the data by the variable "g", keeping the last non missing obserbation of each varianle.

Input:

```
d <- data.table(a=c(1,NA,3,4),b=c(1,2,3,4),c=c(NA,NA,'c',NA),g=c(1,1,2,2))
```

Desired output

```
d_g <- data.table(a=c(1,4),b=c(2,4),c=c(NA,'c'),g=c(1,2))
```

data.table (or dplyr) solution prefered here

OBS:this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143220/select-last-row-by-group-for-all-columns-data-table), but the main answers there seem to cause unecessary NAs in some groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

d[, lapply(.SD, function(x) last(na.omit(x))), g]

#   g a b    c
#1: 1 1 2 <NA>
#2: 2 4 4    c
```

Answer (score 3):

One option using `dplyr` could be:

```
d %>%
 group_by(g) %>%
 summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else last(na.omit(.))))

      g     a     b c    
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     1     2 <NA> 
2     2     4     4 c
```

Answer (score 2):

In *base* `aggregate`could be used.

```
aggregate(.~g, d, function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1), na.action = NULL)
#  g a b c
#1 1 1 2  
#2 2 4 4 c
```